# Why does the Jennifer Robi vs Merck case show two jury trial dates?

Tags: trial

The following case seems to show a jury trial date of July 11, 2022 and also May 1, 2023.

Why are there two trial dates?

https://trellis.law/case/BC628589/JENNIFER-ROBI-VS-MERCK-CO-INC-ET-AL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the case was scheduled for trial, and then the trial was rescheduled to a later date.